# node Linux/Windows compatibility issues

Tags: node.js

This Code works on Windows without any errors.

```
var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , async = require('async')
    , bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    , cookies = require('cookies')
    , cors = require('cors')
    , fileUpload = require('multer')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , moment = require('moment')
    , morgan = require('morgan')
    , path = require('path')
    , session = require('express-session')
    , upload = fileUpload({ dest: './uploads' })
    , uuid = require('uuid')
    ;

var connLaw = require('./nodeHelperFunctions/datasources').service
    , connPG = require('./nodeHelperFunctions/datasources').postgis
    , headers = require('./helperHtml/headers')
    , footers = require('./helperHtml/footers')
    , passCheck = require('./nodeHelperFunctions/hashsalt')
    ;
```

However when the same code is run on an Amazon Linux AMI box, I get the following error.

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './nodeHelperFunctions/datasources'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/testbed/js/app.js:17:59)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

tried changing my code to

```
var connLaw = require(path.join(__dirname, 'nodeHelperFunctions/datasources')).service
    , connPG = require(path.join(__dirname, 'nodeHelperFunctions/datasources')).postgis
    , headers = require(path.join(__dirname, 'helperHtml/headers'))
    , footers = require(path.join(__dirname, 'helperHtml/footers'))
    , passCheck = require(path.join(__dirname, 'nodeHelperFunctions/hashsalt'))
    ;
```

again works perfectly in Windows but got a similar error on Linux:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ec2-user/testbed/js/nodeHelperFunctions/datasources'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/testbed/js/app.js:17:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

how can I get person scripts I have written myself to work on Linux when they work perfecting fine on Windows?

Comment: `/home/ec2-user/testbed/js/nodeHelperFunctions/datasources` is this the correct path?  where is the "nodeHelperFunctions" dir?

Comment: @akaphenom this is probably the right answer, try change the path names from  cammelCase to dash, or even underscore format

Comment: @saul is right you, if you use dashes it takes case sensitivity out of the equation. I (now) use dashes for all file and directory names, and camelCase for variables inside of the scripts.  I have been burned by this many years ago (ok 2014) and switched to Ubuntu development environment at that time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell with what you posted - but requiring modules on linux  is case sensitive to the file name, and windows... ...not so.  Try checking the case.

edit: not just the filename - but the entire path.

Comment: found that my filename was actually dataSources.js
Updated my code and this fixed my issues